# Run script after foreach list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using an external javascript library called Jarvismenu for my knockout app menu and in order to make the menu work (collapse/expand parent menu items when clicking on them) a script needs to be executed after the menu has loaded.

The menu looks like this:

```html
<nav>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: reports">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {title: title}"><span class="menu-item-parent" data-bind="text:title"></span></a>
      <ul data-bind="foreach: reportItems">
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {title: title}, text: title"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>            
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I achieve this in knockout 3.3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

segFault's answer helped but afterRender apparantly runs every time an item is added to the `ul`. What I had to do was in the afterRender function check if the last item was added like this:

```js
functionToCallWhenReportsRendered: function (elements, data) {
    if ($('#unorderedListId').children().length === this.myItems().length) {
        // Execute handler
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="unorderedListId" data-bind="foreach: { data: reports, afterRender: functionToCallWhenReportsRendered}">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {title: title}"><span class="menu-item-parent" data-bind="text:title"></span></a>
      <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: reportItems, afterRender: functionToCallWhenItemsRendered}">
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {title: title}, text: title"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>            
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is additional data you can send into your foreach binding. In your case you would be interested in the afterRender option.

Your code would look like this

```
<nav>
  <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: reports, afterRender: functionToCallWhenReportsRendered}">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {title: title}"><span class="menu-item-parent" data-bind="text:title"></span></a>
      <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: reportItems, afterRender: functionToCallWhenItemsRendered}">
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {title: title}, text: title"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>            
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is a link to more documentation:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html